# Unable to include dbconenct.php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a basic user manipulation system with php, but I'm unable to link dbconnect and get connection variable from it.

Here is my code:

dbconnect.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","realestatecompany");
if(!$con) {
 echo "Error";
}
//$con->close();
?>
```

objects.php

```
<?php 
require_once 'dbconnector.php';
class userAccount {
    public $userName;
    public $userPass;
    public $userType;
      public function __construct ($UserName, $Password, $Type, $con) {
        $this->userName = $UserName;
        $this->userPass = $Password;
        $this->userType = $Type;
    }
    public function writeInDB() {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO login (userName,userPass,userType) values (".$this->userName.",".$this->userPass.",".$this->userType.")";
        if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record Added successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error Adding record: " . $conn->error;
        }
    }
    public function editInDB($userNewAccount, $userID) {
        $a = $userNewAccount->userName;
        $b = $userNewAccount->userPass;
        $c = $userNewAccount->userType;
        $sql = "UPDATE login SET userName =".$a.", userPass ='".$b."', userType =".$c." WHERE userID =".$userID;
        echo $sql;
    }
}
$x = new userAccount("Heba", "Taba3", 1, $con);
$x->writeInDB();
```

?>

Output

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: con in D:\xampp\htdocs\swproject\objects.php on line 14

 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on unknown in D:\xampp\htdocs\swproject\objects.php:14 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\swproject\objects.php(29): userAccount->writeInDB() #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\swproject\objects.php on line 14
```

Any help ?

Comment: `dbconnect.php` and `dbconnector.php` are two different things...

Comment: `require_once 'dbconnect.php';` instead of `require_once 'dbconnector.php';`

Comment: Apart from that you did not consider variable scope in your scripts. `$con` in your functions refer to a _local_ variable, local to the scope of the function, not to a global variable that might or might not be set. You have to either inject the variable by handing it over as a call argument to the functions, or you have to declare it as `global` (_very_ ugly and insecure).

Comment: arkascha and anant, just posted wrong names, they're both dbconnector.php and the error is still there

Comment: **Variable scope**, ___Variable scope___, _variables scope_ Oh and I probably ought to mention [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: @TOMP  I would prefer make your connection inside the class and use $con as class member.

Comment: @RahulVyas What has a database connection got to do with a `userAccount` object??

Comment: @Riggs you are right :) I mean to say using connection as a base class.

Comment: @RahulVyas Now thats also a bad idea. `userAccount` is not an extension of `Database`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is variable scope and also that you forgot to save the `$con` parameter you pass to the `__contruct()` as a property of your class and were not using it as a propery of your class

```
<?php 

require_once 'dbconnector.php';  //<-- should this be 'dbconnect.php`

class userAccount {
    public $userName;
    public $userPass;
    public $userType;

    public $con;

    public function __construct ($UserName, $Password, $Type, $con) {
        $this->userName = $UserName;
        $this->userPass = $Password;
        $this->userType = $Type;
        $this->con      = $con;
    }

    public function writeInDB() {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO login 
                     (userName,userPass,userType) 
                values (".$this->userName.",".$this->userPass.
                        ",".$this->userType.")";

        if ($this->con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record Added successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error Adding record: " . $conn->error;
        }
    }

    public function editInDB($userNewAccount, $userID) {
        $a = $userNewAccount->userName;
        $b = $userNewAccount->userPass;
        $c = $userNewAccount->userType;
        $sql = "UPDATE login SET userName =".$a.", userPass ='".$b."', userType =".$c." WHERE userID =".$userID;
        echo $sql;
    }
}
$x = new userAccount("Heba", "Taba3", 1, $con);
$x->writeInDB();
```